# Should an API return 404 or 428 when resource is not found and If-Match is missing?

Tags: rest, web-services, http, http-status-codes

A client sends a `PUT` or `DELETE` request on a resource:

```
/users/user_id
```

If the resource has been deleted, he gets a `404`.

If he doesn't provide the `If-Match` header, he gets a `428`.

If he doesn't provide the `If-Match` header *and* the resource has been deleted, what should the API return?

It would seem reasonable to return a `404` if the resource does not exist, whether the request is correctly formulated or not. After all the resource does not exist in the first place. I'm trying to act on something that does not exist and whatever I do is bound to fail.

But from a practical perspective, a `428` can be returned immediately without even checking the existence of the element in the database.

---

I'm realizing that this question also applies to a `PUT` with wrong data. In my API, this will trigger a `422` as validation of the input happens first. Is this the right behaviour?

Likewise, when `POST`ing on that `/users/user_id`, my API returns a `405` (Method not allowed) even if `user_id` does not exist, not a `404`. This is how the framework I'm using (Python Flask) works, not a personal design choice.

Comment: OK, this question has been put on hold without a comment... Does this mean that both response statuses are acceptable? This would have been an acceptable answer.

Comment: I think it's a valid question. Voted to reopen.

Comment: I hoped someone could point me to some RFC excerpt to back this up, but the examples I added to the question make me feel totally comfortable with the `428` choice.